# What limitations does the trial version of 3DS Max have

Tags: 3d-graphics, 3ds-max

Does anyone know what limitations the 30-day trial version of 3D Studio Max has?

Is it just that it expires after 30 days, or are there additional limitations during the 30 days such as a watermark or not being able to save or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expires after 30 days, that is it. Though you can register for a student account (if you are a student) and get a 13 month license free.

Answer (score -1):

Aren't the student licenses valid for 3 years?

In a student license there are watermarks when saving and exporting (at least the autocad applications, don't know about 3ds max), so i think there were some limitations or watermarks in the trial, too.

Comment: This is more of a comment than a real answer